# Compare the values of a Dataframe column with a list and maintain the order of the strings from the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words that I want to match the words within a column of a dataframe and store only those words that match. The problem is that the words are stored according to the order of the list, and I want to keep the original order of the dataframe. This is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Boston Red Sox', 'Chicago White Sox']})
```

and i have a list of strings:

```
my_list = ['Red', 'Sox', 'White']
```

The outcome that I want looks like this:

```
       a     
0  Red Sox  
1  White Sox
```

However im having the next outcome:

```
       a     
0  Red Sox  
1  Sox White
```

The code that im using until now is:

```
df['a'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in my_list if i.lower() in x['a'].lower().split()]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string in the dataframe and compare it to the strings in `my_list`:

```py
my_list = ['Red', 'Sox', 'White']

df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda s: ' '.join(w for w in s.split() if w.capitalize() in my_list))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   a          b
0     Boston Red Sox    Red Sox
1  Chicago White Sox  White Sox
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `apply` and simply do a *double-listcomp* :

```
df["a"] = [" ".join([w for w in r.split() if w in my_list]) for r in df["a"]]
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

           a
0    Red Sox
1  White Sox
```